# How do you add padding for the bottom half of the screen in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

So i used padding for this window
[the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pL74.png)
but as you can see the bottom doesn't have padding.

I tried searching it up but there wasn't anything helpful to solve this issue
and I tried using padding for the buttons but it ended up like this.
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7uqz.png)
also here's the code

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage, Label, Button

PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
workmin = 24
seconds = 59
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
TIMESDONE = 0

root = Tk()
root.title(string="Pomodoro work")
root.config(padx=224, pady=100, bg=YELLOW)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
tomato_png = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 112, image=tomato_png)
canvas.create_text(100, 130, text="00.00", fill="white", font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
logo = Label(text="Timer", fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 70, "bold"))
logo.pack()
times_done = Label(text="✘✘✘✘", fg=RED, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
times_done.place(x=55.5, y=350)
canvas.pack()

start = Button(text="Start", font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
start.place(x=-139, y=350)
reset = Button(text="reset", font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
reset.place(x=250, y=350)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the colours in tkinter should be strings. so `YELLOW` -> `"yellow"`

Comment: also the variable `FONT_NAME` is not defined.

Comment: You should not use `place()` on the two buttons and the `xxxx` label.  Put them inside another frame (using `pack()` or `grid()`) and use `pack()` on the frame.

Comment: Using Win10, Python 3.12.2. Your code is working.  On line 31, change this to `reset.place(x=280, y=350)` instead of `x=250`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) set the dimensions of your root window using the `geometry` property.

So instead of using `padx` and `pady` to size your window:

```
root.config(padx=224, pady=100, bg='yellow')
```

you should use:

```
root.geometry('224x100')  # or whatever '<width>x<height>' you want
```

Note that the dimensions

- must be a string
- correspond to '<width>x<height>' in pixels

`geometry` supports a few other options which you can read about [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-geometry-method-in-tkinter/), and you can of course use this in conjunction with `configure` so you can keep the yellow background (though you can probably skip the `padding`!)

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer worked for you, please mark it as "Accepted" (by clicking the check mark) so that others know this question has been answered.

Comment: The start button is missing( offset). if using this `root.geometry('224x100')`

Comment: @toyotaSupra OP’s widget placement(s) will have to be updated, yes. This is why I tend to advocate for using `pack` and advise against using `place`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the paddings configured by the following line:

```py
root.config(padx=224, pady=100, bg=YELLOW)
```

You should not use `.place()` on the two buttons and the "xxxx" label.  Use a frame to hold them and use `.pack()` on the frame.

Updated code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage, Label, Button, Frame

PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
workmin = 24
seconds = 59
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
TIMESDONE = 0

root = Tk()
root.title(string="Pomodoro work")
root.config(padx=224, pady=100, bg=YELLOW)

logo = Label(root, text="Timer", fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 70, "bold"))
logo.pack()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

tomato_png = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 112, image=tomato_png)
canvas.create_text(100, 130, text="00.00", fill="white", font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))

# create a frame for the two buttons and "xxxx" label
frame = Frame(root, bg=YELLOW)
frame.pack()

# create the two buttons and the label as children of frame

start = Button(frame, text="Start", font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
start.pack(side="left")

times_done = Label(frame, text="✘✘✘✘", fg=RED, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
times_done.pack(side="left", padx=100)

reset = Button(frame, text="reset", font=("Courier", 20, "normal"))
reset.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Note also that it is better to specify the parent of widgets when creating them.